# How do I install a "standard" version of Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I've installed Firefox the typical way:

```
$ apt install firefox
```

But what was installed isn't a typical Firefox browser.  It's been peppered with a bunch of Ubuntu-specific stuff that I don't want.  Two examples that I find particularly annoying:

- When I do a search from the location bar (just type a query and hit enter) it takes me to `https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=my+query`.  Note the `t=canonical` in there -- I don't want that.
- The keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` doesn't switch to the previous tab like it does on every other Firefox install I've used over the years.  I'm assuming this is also some kind of Canonical tampering.

So what's the right way to install "real" Firefox if you're using Ubuntu?  Mozilla is happy to let me download a source tarball, but I'm not even sure how best to use that on an apt-based system.  Are there "clean" `.deb` packages I can use?  Is there a standard way to clean a typical *Ubuntuised* install?  I'd be happy to use the "developer edition" if that's an option.

#### Update

I've downloaded the standard Firefox locally and run it and the same above behaviour persists, which is just *weird*.  `Ctrl+Tab` lets me cycle forward through my tabs, but `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` does nothing.  On my Arch system the latter cycles backward through my tabs, but on Ubuntu, regardless of whether I'm using Firefox-from-tarball or Firefox-from-apt, there's no cycling backward.

As for the `t=canonical` thing, I'm beginning to think that that might be something that Firefox is appending based on some OS-detection.  If I change my search provider from DuckDuckGo to Google, the querystring is modified *not* to include `t=canonical` but rather `client=ubuntu`.  In either case however, if I use the search engine normally by vising the page directly and using their search bar, the querystring is unmolested.

Comment: Those 2 are settings you can change within firefox. No need to install another firefox if that is all.

Comment: Great!  How do I do that?  Going into preferences, I didn't see anything relating to keyboard shortcuts or the mangling of the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the `.deb` packages but there is `.tar.bz2` file to download from [Firefox website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/linux/). There are installation instructions as well.

EDIT:
I found a simpler way. There's `xul-ext-ubufox` package installed described as *Ubuntu modifications for Firefox*, try removing it and see if that helps.

Comment: Nice spot on the `xul-ext-ubufox` thing.  I've removed it, but unfortunately, I haven't seen any change in the above items.  I even started Firefox with a new profile!  Still both problems remain.  I'm beginning to think it might be some sort of default behaviour for Ubuntu systems.

Comment: @DanielQuinn The only way to get a firefox that's not touched by the Canonical development team is to install yourself from source or tarball.  Unfortunately, it is then up to you to keep it updated at that point and you lose all Security team rapid patching for new security issues.